# Would this work - Public Class

Tags: java, class, methods

I would like to know if the following code should work:

```
if (M != 0){

    Tools.Printer(stdnr);

    }
```

Background Info:

I created a public class Tools with a few functions. One of the functions is the void Printer function. Is there a rule or something that if you want to use Tools.something you need to do assign the Tools.something to an integer / print it, etc. Or is Tools.Printer supposed to work on its own.

I ask this because I can't find anything wrong with my code. I would be glad if someone can help me right with the terms I used above - I suppose they are terribly wrong...

Thank a lot, Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are going to need to post a little more code than that.

Comment: Is Printer a static method? If not, you need to create a new instance of the Tools class.

Comment: A method can have a void return type, so you certainly aren't forced to consume it.  What error are you getting?

Comment: @James - Yes Printer is a static method. Let's say it wasn't - what would "create a new instance of the Tools class" mean? I'm kinda new to programming - enjoy it VERY much - would like to know more... @Kirk - I'm not getting an error. The program is supposed to write to a txt file - it worked until I decided to rather use a method in a Class as I'm going to print a lot of thing to the text file later on... to run the program I use "java Database 50 20 > text.txt" in the terminal. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method is a void type, it returns **nothing**, therefore you do not need to assign it to a variable (in fact, you'll get a compile time error if you do).

If it was instead a function, like it returned some value, for instance:

```
public String foo()
{
 return "kdfldj";
}
```

You still don't necessary need to assign it to a variable. The returned value will just be discarded. For example, [StringBuilder.append](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28boolean%29) returns back the StringBuilder that you just appended to, but you can safely call it like this:

```
myStringBuilder.append("some text");
```

And ignore the return value.

However, if your `Tools.Printer` method is not a `static` method, you do need to create an instance of Tools, either assigned to a variable like this:

```
Tools tools = new Tools();
tools.Printer(stdnr);
```

or initialized without being placed in a variable:

```
new Tools().Printer(stdnr);
```

But if `Printer` is a static method, your code should be fine, since you are calling the method by the class it's contained in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. What does "you do need to create an instance of Tools" - is this something to do with object oriented programming?

Comment: @ISJ Create an instance means create a new object from a class, like `String j = new String("Hi");` creates a new instance of a String